# How to pass a PHP $_GET variable and fetch/output it?

Tags: php, urls, variables

I've already looked at the Wordpress Codex, and looked around for other solutions online, but i still can't seem to get it working.
Basicly what i need is to pass a GET variable in an URL, and output it on the next page.

Link `http://www.website.com?foo=bar`

I've aleady tried fetching the GET variable like below:
`$foo = get_query_var( 'foo' );
echo $foo;`
And doesn't seem to work.

Also tried the more PHP oriented way:
`$foo = $_GET['foo'];`
Also, without success.

Any help on the matter would be most appreciated.

Comment: It's strange that `$_GET['foo']` doesn't work. What about standard WordPress query variables, does `?s=foo` in the URL result in a search? Can you output `$_GET['s']` in the code?

Comment: Yes, `?s=foo` redirects to the search(results) page.

Answer (score 2):

`get_query_var()` only works with the Core `WP_Query` object:

> Retrieve public query variable in the `WP_Query` class of the `global
>   $wp_query` object.
>
> https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var

Your mistake is a simple PHP one: The key is `foo`, not `bar`.

```
$foo = $_GET['foo'];
echo $foo;
```

But please do not `echo` user supplied data to the page without [sanitizing it](https://codex.wordpress.org/Validating_Sanitizing_and_Escaping_User_Data).

Comment: Whoops, edited the question. In my actual code i had the key right though. But still, nothing.

On the codex page it says<br>
`$page = get_query_var( 'page', 1 );`
With 'page' being the key, and the '1' being the default value? I've just tried this and also doesn't work for me.
Then again, isn't that what i've already tried before? (See question).